# How to remove jquery migrate on selected posts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

There are working solutions to remove jquery-migrate ([popular solution](https://www.infophilic.com/remove-jquery-migrate-wordpress/)), however NONE for selected posts.

The problem is that they all rely on `wp_default_scripts` hook, where post id is not defined yet. As a result `is_front_page() || is_home()` will fail.

Question: How can I remove jquery-migrate for all posts BUT keep it on home page/front page?

Answer (score -1):

You can run the following code on any page you want
For example, to run the code only on single pages, it is enough to put the code inside the condition
Set `if(is_single()){ //code }`

In any case, you can put the code in the `functions.php` file unconditionally to remove jQuery Migrate.

```
function dequeue_jquery_migrate( $scripts ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && ! empty( $scripts->registered['jquery'] ) ) {
    $scripts->registered['jquery']->deps = array_diff(
      $scripts->registered['jquery']->deps,
      [ 'jquery-migrate' ]
    );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'dequeue_jquery_migrate');
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry, ```is_single``` will not work same as ```is_home() || is_front_page()```. And, your suggestion will not exclude the home page.